# Empty request body on "Android Profiler"

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-profiler

Previously using okhttp interceptor, a complete json request was printed on "Android Monitor" portion of the android studio.

[image]

Now after updating android studio to 3.1, there is "Android Profiler" option in place of the "Android Monitor" to log request-response. Following is link I followed to work with "Android Profiler".

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-analyze-network-traffic-with-android-studio-profiler

The "Android Profiler" prints response body but request body (on request tab) is always empty.

[image]

How to print complete json request body through the "Android Profiler". Thank you

Comment: I'm facing even worse problems. I can see only the headers of the request, but neither the headers of the answer, nor any of the bodies. :?